# ListPlot under conditions Part II

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

I have a data file containing several columns and thousands lines of data. Below I present a small portion of it, in order to express my issue:

```
-6.00000000          -0.50000000   0.2012925952067529E+01   -.1354335628382003E+01   -.1226489717949115E+01   0.3971000000000000E+02   0.3563073636222663E-02    8
-6.00000000          -0.40000000   -.1667709017102080E+01   0.1996988297249126E+01   -.8819770483714856E+00   0.2608000000000000E+02   0.7532864609099250E-05    6
-6.00000000          -0.30000000   -.1790107106742991E+01   -.1663230917261907E+01   0.1128076001589623E+01   0.2088000000000000E+02   0.3177221419972102E-02    3
-6.00000000          -0.20000000   -.1705528943436493E+01   -.1416493048162809E+01   -.1473371717762452E+01   0.1974000000000000E+02   0.1287464426169665E-04    7
-6.00000000          -0.10000000   -.1438853964633666E+01   0.8237153975034051E+00   0.2328464291089728E+01   0.1852000000000000E+02   0.4189535638506170E-02    2
-6.00000000           0.00000000   -.7656851229280424E+00   -.1226763235452721E+01   -.2690993457287972E+01   0.4270000000000000E+02   0.1253249246603346E-11    7
-6.00000000           0.10000000   0.2359731627744364E+01   -.1081845089584134E+01   -.1195510444527736E+01   0.3603000000000000E+02   0.3777453269309895E-06    8
```

The first two columns correspond to the coordinates $x$ and $y$. I have a MMA code (is given below) for plotting the coordinates $(x,y)$ and assign to each point a color according to the value of the sixth column. The last column has an integer which takes values inside the interval [0,8].

```
input = ReadList["data18.out", Number, RecordLists -> True];
input2 = ReadList["data0.out", Number, RecordLists -> True];

data = Table[{input[[i, 1]], input[[i, 2]], Log10[input[[i, 6]]]}, {i,1, Length[input]}];
data2 = Table[{input2[[i, 1]], input2[[i, 3]]}, {i, 1, Length[input2]}];

Clear[colorbar]
colorbar[{min_, max_}, colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 150] := 
DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, min, max}, AspectRatio -> 10, 
PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {{None, 
 Row[{Subscript["log", "10"], "(", Subscript["t", "esc"], 
   ")"}]}, {None, None}}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 17], 
FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 15, Plain], 
ColorFunction -> colorFunction]

V = ω^2/2*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + ϵ*(x^2*y^2 + x^2*z^2 + 
  y^2*z^2 - x^2*y^2*z^2);
Vxy = V /. {z -> 0};
ω = ϵ = 1;
E0 = 8.5;
z0 = 0.1;
xmin = 4.5;

f[x_, px_] := 1/2*px^2 + V /. {y -> 0, z -> z0};

plrange = {{-xmin, xmin}, {-xmin, xmin}};
valrange = {0, 5};

C0 = ContourPlot[Evaluate[f[x, px]], {x, -5, 5}, {px, -5, 5}, 
Contours -> {E0}, ContourStyle -> {{Black, Thickness[0.003]}}, 
AspectRatio -> 1, ContourShading -> False, PlotPoints -> 200, 
PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", PlotRange -> plrange];

L0 = ListPlot[data2, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0.011]}];

With[{opts = {ImageSize -> {Automatic, 550}}, cf = "Rainbow"}, 
Row[{Show[
ListPlot[List /@ data[[All, {1, 2}]], 
 PlotStyle -> ({PointSize[0.01], ColorData[cf][1 - #]} & /@ 
    Rescale[data[[All, 3]], valrange]), PlotRange -> plrange, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, RotateLabel -> False, 
 Axes -> None, FrameTicks -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Subscript["x", "0"], 
   OverDot[Subscript["x", "0"]]}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 17], 
 ImagePadding -> {{60, 20}, {60, 20}}, opts], C0, L0], 
Show[colorbar[valrange, ColorData[cf][1 - #] &], 
ImagePadding -> {{20, 60}, {60, 20}}, opts]}]]
```

The `data18.out` file contains all the data. However, if there is a zero at the last column I want the corresponding points to be plotted in black; only when 1-8 the rainbow colors should apply. So, in order plot with in black these points, I extracted them in a separate file `data0.out`. What I want is instead of using two files, to use only the original `data_all.out` file. I suppose that and `IF` condition is possible inside the `ListPlot`

Here is the final output

[image: grid]

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The complete data file can be found here: [data](http://www.mediafire.com/view/j4m4aoq0iogd87i/data_all.out)

**EDIT 2**

A revised working MMA notebook can be downloaded from here: [code](http://www.mediafire.com/view/58lmlrrb2x02u1f/Esc_tst.nb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `data` was to hold information also about the last column a new color function could be defined like this:

```
colfunc[x_] := If[x[[8]] == 0, Black, ColorData[cf][1 - x[[3]]]]
```

`x[[8]]` is supposed to be the value from the last column. `x[[3]]` is supposed to be the data that determines the color in the ordinary case. However, this would have to have been rescaled beforehand, something like:

```
data[[All,3]]=Rescale[data[[All,3]],valrange]
```

You guessed yourself that `If` would do it and I'm sure you are correct. Do you think you could make this work? Step one is to import all data into the `data` list. Each row should simply correspond to a row in your data files. Then inside `Listplot`: `colfunc/@data` after data has already been rescaled.

**EDIT: Since I now have the data I've tried implement the solution fully.**

The first changes I wanted to make was in how the data was imported, so that we have all the information in the list `data`. But in order to do so we need to define `valrange` early on, so I also changed the order of that:

```
plrange = {{-xmin, xmin}, {-xmin, xmin}};
valrange = {0, 5};
data = Import["~/Desktop/data_all.out", "Table"];
data[[All, 6]] = Rescale[Log10[data[[All, 6]]], valrange];
```

Now defining the color function:

```
colfunc[x_, cf_] := If[x[[8]] == 0, Black, ColorData[cf][1 - x[[6]]]]
```

And the rest of the code which I haven't changed:

```
Clear[colorbar]
colorbar[{min_, max_}, colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 150] := 
 DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, min, max}, AspectRatio -> 10, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{None, 
     Row[{Subscript["log", "10"], "(", Subscript["t", "esc"], 
       ")"}]}, {None, None}}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 17], 
  FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 15, Plain], 
  ColorFunction -> colorFunction]
V = ω^2/
     2*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + ϵ*(x^2*y^2 + x^2*z^2 + y^2*z^2 - 
      x^2*y^2*z^2);
Vxy = V /. {z -> 0};
ω = ϵ = 1;
E0 = 8.5;
z0 = 0.1;
xmin = 4.5;
f[x_, px_] := 1/2*px^2 + V /. {y -> 0, z -> z0};
C0 = ContourPlot[Evaluate[f[x, px]], {x, -5, 5}, {px, -5, 5}, 
   Contours -> {E0}, ContourStyle -> {{Black, Thickness[0.003]}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ContourShading -> False, PlotPoints -> 200, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", PlotRange -> plrange];
```

And finally, the piece of code which I have changed. Look carefully at the row where the color function is being used:

```
With[{opts = {ImageSize -> {Automatic, 550}}, cf = "Rainbow"}, Row[{
   Show[
    ListPlot[
     List /@ data[[All, {1, 2}]],
     PlotStyle -> ({PointSize[0.01], colfunc[#, cf]} & /@ data), 
     PlotRange -> plrange,
     AspectRatio -> 1,
     Frame -> True,
     RotateLabel -> False,
     Axes -> None,
     FrameTicks -> True,
     FrameLabel -> {Subscript["x", "0"], 
       OverDot[Subscript["x", "0"]]}, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 17],
     ImagePadding -> {{60, 20}, {60, 20}}, opts
     ], C0],
   Show[colorbar[valrange, ColorData[cf][1 - #] &], 
    ImagePadding -> {{20, 60}, {60, 20}}, opts]
   }]
 ]
```

[image: circleplot]

Well, as you can see the colors are different. It has to do with the scaling, or with the data manipulation at import (`Log10` and so on, might've missed something there). Surely the OP will be able to rescale the data as he wishes, but the black dots are exactly where they are supposed to be as far as I can tell.

Comment: It seems that this is what I want. However, I cannot figure out what to change. See my EDIT; I added a link to the complete data file. If you want incorporate your solution to my original code and see if the output is the same.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Is it the same as data18.out in your code?

Comment: No, the file I uploaded has all the values, from 0 to 8 at eighth column. At the original code, we read to different external files data18 and data0. Now only one file should be read (the data_all). Whenever there is 0 the (x,y) point should be plotted in black, otherwise according to the rainbow pallet.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z OK, I understand.

Comment: valrange={0,5} determines the minimum and maximum values of the colorbar and it's irrelevant with what I want! Have you managed to incorporate your solution to the code?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Yes I have and the black dots are exactly in the same places as in your graph but I get different colors, and I suspect it's because of the rescaling. But I'll post and let you figure that out.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z It may also be because of the different file formats; I may have misidentified some column as the column with the color data.

Comment: let me play with it a little bit and I 'll come back to you!

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z I had mistaken column 6 for column 3 in a few spots. I corrected that. Still not the same plot, but closer.

Comment: I made a few changes and everything is working fine now. See my new EDIT 2 with the complete working code. Thanks again! I am wondering, if it is possible to include more assumptions in the IF of the color function (i.e. 0 at 8th column and > 0.1 at the seventh, etc)

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z You're welcome. Yes, it's absolutely possibly, `If[x[[8]] == 0 && x[[7]]>0.1 ...` and so on.